# Share multiple Google Calendars without embedding them manually

Tags: google-calendar

I am trying to share multiple calendars (school, work, etc) with a friend. I would just like to link them to a single page containing all of the calendars combined since the person with whom I am sharing this with does not use Google Calendar. I see you can set up a HTML link to a single calendar, but is it possible to display several calendars at once?

Edit: It is possible to do so by editing the URL of the page, but then all the entries are the same color and it's hard to tell the difference between the calendars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the dropdown box next to a calendar on the left side of google calendar. Click "calendar settings". Scroll down and select "Customize the color, size, and other options" in the section for "embed this calendar". Select the calendars you want to display and set the colors as you wish and change whatever other settings you want to. Then, copy the generated HTML and embed it into an html file wherever it is you want to provide this page. If you don't have your own hosting, then you can just extract the iframe's source link from the generated HTML and just point your friend there.

Answer (score 1):

[nhinkle's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9055/share-multiple-google-calendars-without-embedding-them-manually/9066#9066) worked for me but there was a problem with generating the code to show the navigation arrows and tabs.

I had to add `showNav=1&amp;showTabs=1&amp;` to the embedded code to display them. The generated code seemed to assume they were on by default and only generates these options if you deselect them.

Answer (score 1):

In the calendar settings, you can find the extra options for sharing your calendar.  Have it generate the iframe code for you. Part of that code is the calendar source and it looks something like this:

```
&amp;src=7sqqkm9545qun10j0t2t2r8akk%40group.calendar.google.com
```

That `&amp;` is simply the code way of stating `&` and the `%40` is the code version of `@`.

So you need to add in the source for a second calendar. Find the source for the second calendar and change the `@` to `%40`.

```
7sqqkblahblahblahblah@group.calendar.google.com
```

becomes

```
7sqqkblahblahblahblah%40group.calendar.google.com
```

Then insert into the iframe code the src for the second calendar, like so:

```
&amp;src=7sqqkblahblahblahblah%40group.calendar.google.com
```

Here is what the iframe code looks like to start:

```
&lt;iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showPrint=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTz=0&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=7sqqkm9557qun1oj0t2t2r8akk%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23B1440E&amp;ctz=America%2FNew_York" style="border-width: 0;" frameborder="0" height="600" scrolling="no" width="100%"&gt;
```

and here is the second iframe code with two calendars' src codes.

```
&lt;iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showPrint=0&amp;showCalendars=0&amp;showTz=0&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=isprj5h0d4uv3hs59iqt7u76kc%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;src=7sqqkm9557qun1oj0t2t2r8akk%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23B1440E&amp;ctz=America%2FNew_York" style="border-width: 0;" frameborder="0" height="600" scrolling="no" width="100%"&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to do so with Teamup Calendar.  It could look like:
http://lopsdato.no/  or
http://presentationtimes.com/

Do you need to keep your original calendars in Google or can they be somewhere else?  If so, you can create your own calendar easily from teamup.com and add up to 10 calendars for free, each color-coded.  You can share any number of calendars in any combination of access rights (read-only, modifiable, etc.) by configuring the access links from Settings then Sharing (accessible only to the administrator, usually the calendar creator).  Using simple iframe to embed one of the appropriate access links into your page.

There are several video tutorials including "Getting Started" and "How to Share" at teamup.com which could help you get up to speed quickly.  And check out the blog post detailing how it is different from sharing Google Calendars.

Answer (score 0):

I found a much more convenient solution than presented in the other answers here.

First, for each calendar that you want to share, update the settings so that the free/busy info is publicly available (you could make the details publicly available as well if you like).

Then, create a link like this:

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=me%40gmail.com&src=me%40mydomain.com&ctz=America%2FNew_York
```

using the gmail and G Suite email addresses of the calendars you want to share.  The %40 is a special representation of the @ character in an email address.

You can share this link with anyone, and they will see a nice page showing your calendar info.  You can add more Google accounts, and you can add more options to the link by looking at the description of the embeddable iframe calendar that you can get to from Google calendar settings.

Answer (score -4):

Just use the Google [Embeddable Calendar Helper](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embedhelper).

Comment: How would someone do this? Where is this helper? Whilst this might be true it doesn't provide any details or steps to use it.

Comment: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embedhelper